# 2D convolution using openCV in C

Tags: c, opencv, convolution

I want to implement a program which performs the 2D convolution using openCV. I'm new with openCV. my naive implementation is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
//used for kernel
unsigned short int kernel[3][3] __attribute__(( aligned(32)));                                          
// input and output image
unsigned short int input[512][512] __attribute__(( aligned(32)));
unsigned short int output[512][512] __attribute__((aligned(32)));

int main()
{
    //data are assigned to input and kernel matrices before.
    const CvArr* src = input;
    CvArr* dst = output;
    const CvMat* kernel = kernel; // return error incompatible pointer type
    CvPoint anchor=cvPoint(-1,-1); // ? 
    cvFilter2D(src,  dst, kernel, anchor); // want to multiply the kernel as it should do in 2D convolution program

    return 0;
}
```

I know it's not correct. can anyone help me to correct this implementation?
I also can not understand the anchor! I studied and searched many links, these links might be helpful: [2D matrices with CvMat in OpenCV](http://aishack.in/tutorials/2d-matrices-cvmat-opencv/) [CvMat Struct Reference](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/db2/structCvMat.html) the C implementation of convolution program can be seen in this question: [Fast 2D Convolution in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105132/fast-2d-convolution-in-c)

I use `gcc`, `Linux mint` and `Skylake`

The build command is `gcc  -Wall  pkg-config --libs opencv pkg-config --cflags opencv  -march=native  -D _GNU_SOURCE -O2  -o  "%e" "%f"`

I use `-D _GNU_SOURCE` to assign the program to a single core of the CPU. Is it correct to restrict the openCV? Because I want to check the performance on a single core.

**UPDATE** The goal of this implementation is a comparison between My Convolution implementation with another fast implementation on CPU. Is comparing to openCV a good idea? If not what is the best way? If yes is there any differences between C, C++ and java version for comparison? I mean my basic program is written in C does it make any sense to compare the program with C++ which uses `g++` instead `gcc` and of course objects, etc.

Comment: Please don't use depreciated C API's for which you won't get any support. Try to read some documentation! Refer this http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/filter_2d/filter_2d.html

Comment: The problem is solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150525/why-this-code-returns-segmentation-fault-error/43152039#43152039)