# How to apply multi-threading approach on filter2D function of OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, simd, convolution

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150525/why-this-code-returns-segmentation-fault-error/43152039#43152039) question, I want to compare the performance of the filter2D function to my multi-threaded version of SIMDized 2D convolution. For my implementation, AVX2, I use `#omp parallel for` before the for loops but the filter2D is like a black box in this implementation. One not tested solution might be using the `pthreads` library to perform a number of filter2D on the different part of the `Mat`. But, this solution is not a gentle one. What should I do to use threads in filter2D function and compare it to the multi-threaded SIMD implementation, reasonably?

Comment: "...using the pthreads library..." - or just use [`cv::parallel_for_`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d7/dff/tutorial_how_to_use_OpenCV_parallel_for_.html)?

Comment: Where should I put `cv::parallel_for_`?

Comment: I meant as an alternative to having to implement all the boilerplate "to perform a number of filter2D on the different part of the `Mat` [in parallel]" using a low level API like pthreads.

Comment: I have tested but there are no threads. I have built `opencv 3.4` AVX2 enabled.